# Maximum date from a given day - sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have dates in tables:

```
2018-09-01 02:22:23
2018-09-01 02:22:25
2018-09-01 02:22:28
2018-09-02 02:22:22
2018-09-02 02:30:00

SELECT * FROM table_name where columnA =  order by 1 desc;
```

columnA is TIMESTAMP

I would like it to return the maximum date from that day. Does anyone know how this query should look like?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: With that sample table data, what's the expected result?

Comment: Oracle. Expected result are: 2018-09-01 02:22:28, 2018-09-02 02:30:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query should look like -

The below is for a specific date -

```
select max(columnA) from table_name
 where trunc(columnA) = date 'yyyy-mm-dd' ;-- this is for oracle
 --      where date(columnA) = 'yyyy-mm-dd' ;-- this is for mysql
```

A solution could also be, if you require it to be generic, so as to give max timestamp for each day -

```
select max(A.columnA) from table_name A
  group by trunc(A.columnA); -- this is for oracle
  -- group by date(A.columnA); -- this is for mysql
```

Comment: Note that (in MySQL anyway) this solution cannot use an index, which may make is slow on larger data sets.

Comment: `trunc(timestamp)` returns a date in Oracle, so the first one should be `where trunc(columnA) = date '2018-09-01`, or possibly `where columnA >= date '2018-09-01' and columnA < date '2018-09-02'`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT columnA FROM table_name WHERE where trunc(columnA ) = to_date('2018-09-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD') order by columnA DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: `columnA` is a timestamp, not a string, so that won't work in Oracle unless you `set nls_timestamp_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD'`.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I have updated the query. Initially, a query is based on MySQL.

Comment: Fair enough, the OP didn't make it clear which RDBMS this was for initially.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order by desc` and `limit`

```
SELECT * FROM table 
   ORDER BY date_field DESC
   LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: It returns one result, and I would like to have all the maximum dates from a given day